# Can we change the sample question on the tour?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I was browsing through the tour, and I noticed that the sample question given is currently about unicorns eating daisies. Oof.

Taking my personal opinion of the subject matter out of it, I'll say that this is clearly not a good representation of the questions on the site. Is there any way we can change it? Should we change it?

Comment: That's the default question.  If I remember correctly (from another site), we can change it to another question that meets the requirements of that page.  I'll try to find something definitive on this, but I know that both the question and answers (of which there must be at least two, and positively scored) need to be relatively short and not use any special formatting or images.

Comment: Couldn't find it, so I've asked: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242612/162102

Comment: I guess the problem is that on a programming, language, or religious site, people will *know* that that's a silly placeholder question, but on a site like this, people might think it's real.

Comment: @TriG Exactly. When I saw that when I first joined Worldbuilding, I had second thoughts for a second. . . Then I saw some of the questions and got really interested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can change the question, see here: http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/92078/possible-about-questions

However we need a Q&A on the site that matches those criteria, and so far we have none.

Basically you need a Question and an Answer where both are less than 400 characters long, both have no fancy formatting, and both have a positive score.

The 400 character limit is probably what is killing us.

Comment: Can we artificially devise a sample question and accompanying answers?

Comment: I don't see why not...feel free to suggest a suitable Q&A here (we need a decent short question and 2 decent short answers (preferably actually different not rewording of the same thing)) though.

Comment: We now have two choices; is it worth bringing this back up?

Comment: Scratch that; it was changed already. My bad.